# Visual Studio link to different areas of code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

just wondering is there any feature in visual studio 2010 that allows you to put a link in your comments that take you to another part of the solution. Kind of like the bookmark feature but you go to the bookmark by clicking on the link.

I just think it would be neat to put a link to the unit test for each of my methods.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Resharper then you can navigate to any valid symbol placed in a doc-comment with ctrl-click.

For example

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="AReferencedMethod"/>
/// </summary>
```

Just ctrl-click and you're there.

Unfortunately I'm not sure this would be useful for referencing unit tests since the assembly under test is usually referenced by the unit test assembly not the other way around.

Comment: Personally, I am looking for a simple way to travel instantly to an anchor somewhere in the code from other place in code. Preferrably without third-party plugins or at least freeware ones.

Comment: you could try the bookmarks, and navigate to those via the bookmark windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w13x3hh.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try the [HyperAddin extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/49B1C42B-424B-44CE-9BB1-22B4EC91E577).

Alternatively, if you have the commercial addin [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/), it supports go to (alt+g) in comments, though results will vary depending on how fully scoped symbols are in the comments.  Visual Assist also supports tags in comments that are navigable ([VA Hashtags](https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W574)) and can navigate to files referenced in comments via the [File Viewer Plugin for the Source Links feature](https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W754).

Comment: HyperAddin does not support VS2010.

Answer (score 2):

You can bake in a direct link to a file using the hypertext comment link like this:

`//file://c:\users\project\myfile.cpp`

However that opens the file in the built-in browser, not the code editor, which isn't much use. It also needs the full path as it doesn't seem to register project variables like $(SolutionDir).

However, if anyone on here is savvy at writing Visual Studio Plugins, I think an override of the hyperlink system would be a good place to start to get this working.

: D

Comment: I do believe that "areas of code" implies a certain line in source code file.

Comment: As I said, this isn't a great deal of use, but there is functionality there that I hope could be exploited by a plugin developer. It wouldn't be a stretch to add line numbers. It might even be possible to make the link more symbolic and tie it to actual functions rather than files and line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

[Supercharger](http://supercharger.tools) supports this style of navigation - see its 'Code Links' implementation. Basically, you put `goto:...` constructs in comments and get a visual clickable hotspot.

The following functions are supported:

- `goto:#TagName` navigates to a previously defined tag (with tag:#TagName), can be anywhere in the same project
- `goto:MemberName` navigates to a member within the same class/struct
- `goto:CodeTypeName.MemberName` navigates to a member within the same code file, but in a different class, or to a member within a different code file, if the class name and the code file name are the same
- `goto:FileName\CodeTypeName.MemberName` navigates to a member in a different code file

Disclaimer: I am the creator of Supercharger.